# Adjusting SystemUI Navbar and Status bar according to dark/light theme in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to change the navbar and status bar icon colours for android devices according to dark and light themes in flutter. I have only been successful within manually setting themes:

`SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle( SystemUiOverlayStyle( statusBarColor: Color.fromARGB(85, 0, 0, 0), statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light, systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent, systemStatusBarContrastEnforced: false, systemNavigationBarContrastEnforced: false, ), ); SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);`

I have seen some solutions using AnnotatedRegion and appbartheme, however, I am new to flutter development and can't get these to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](https://www.flutterbeads.com/change-status-bar-color-in-flutter/) outlines your options pretty well. In summary, you can set your system ui colors:

- (a) per `Scaffold` via the `systemOverlayStyle` property in your `AppBar`;
- (b) your entire app via `AppBarTheme` in your `ThemeData`; or
- (c) per region of your app using `AnnotatedRegion`.

Here is an example of option (a) using `MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context)` to set light / dark colors:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MyWidget'),
        systemOverlayStyle: MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context) == Brightness.dark
            ? SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.green.shade900,
                statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
                systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
              )
            : SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.green.shade200,
                statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
              ),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Hello, World!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You use option (b) to set dark / light colors app-wide by providing a light `AppBarTheme` and a dark `AppBarTheme` to your corresponding light / dark `ThemeData` in the `theme` and `darkTheme` properties of your `MaterialApp`.